# My test e-mail is working, but any other e-mail not working on Magento 2

Tags: email, magento2.2.2

My test e-mail is working, but any other e-mail is not working on Magento 2.2.2 version.
I haven't use Cron job, I am using default Magento functionality.
I have already Disable "Asynchronous sending"
Earlier my email is working but when i updated version 2.1.2 to 2.2.2. Email is not working.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked log files?

Comment: Yes, but here is no any message related to Email.